# Applying multiple CSS class names of different natures using ng-class in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have a directive whose structure is:

```
<mydir ng-class="i.labels", ng-class="{'elSelected': i.id == selectedId}"></mydir>
```

Here `i.labels` is a an array of CSS class names and `i.id` and `selectedId` are numbers, all of which are declared inside the controller. I want to apply all the classes contained in the array `i.labels` and conditionally apply `elSelected` to `mydir`. How can I do this with ng-class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` to apply array of classes and use `class` attribute to apply a class conditionally:

```
<mydir ng-class="i.labels" 
class="{{i.id == selectedId? 'elSelected' : ''}}"></mydir>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cC6A9/)**</kbd>